# Call a function on CodeBehind that's operated by a LinkButton (ASP.net, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi StackOverflow Community,

I have this code on CodeBehind:

```
protected void Btn_Search_Function(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GV_Results.PageIndex = 0;
   GV_Results.DataBind();
   hdnSelectedTab.Value = "1";
}
```

This code is executed when I click a **LinkButton**. I want to call this function when another method (in the same page) finishes executing.

But I don't know what arguments to pass as `object sender and EventArgs e`. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Thank you in advance,
Best regards.

Comment: `Btn_Search_Function(null, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a button called Btn_Search and you have created an event handler for the button click event `Btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).`

then, in your another method you can call like:

```
public void my_function()
{
    //This simulates the button click from within your code.
    Btn_Search_Click(Btn_Search, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

or

```
Btn_Search_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

or for your function

```
Btn_Search_Function(null, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after 5 minutes I had the idea of creating a third method that would be called both by the function that is called when I click the LinkButton, and by the method I want to execute the same code.

I'm open to better ways of achieving this.
So, it is has follows:

```
protected void Btn_Search_Function(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchFunction();
}

private void SearchFunction()
{
    GV_Results.PageIndex = 0;
    GV_Results.DataBind();
    hdnSelectedTab.Value = "1";
}
```